# Typewrite. How to make content not move down?

Tags: javascript

When outputting words from a new line, all content shifts down, how can I prevent this? How do I make the text box be a constant size that does not move down when typing?

Here is my code:

```js
var str = "<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum availableThere are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>",
  i = 0,
  isTag,
  text;
  
(function type() {
  text = str.slice(0, ++i);
  if (text === str) return;
  document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML = text;
  var char = text.slice(-1);
  if (char === '<') isTag = true;
  if (char === '>') isTag = false;
  if (isTag) return type();
  setTimeout(type, 80);
}());
```

```html
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```

Comment: Could not understand, what you actually want to ask?

Comment: When the text is displayed, then from each new line there is a shift of all content, that under the cursor, goes down! Understand?

Comment: Nothing is moving down or shifting. Can you elabourate?

Comment: It looks fine in the code snippet, please execute it here and see if the problem is not just in your application, if you see the problem here as well, please explain it in detail.

Comment: The issue is with the word wrap. As you add letters to the word it becomes too large and the browser sends it down a line. You can either play with ` word-wrap` property, or change how the letter reveal mechanism works (e.g. going from transparent to colour)